# What, if any, scientific value do global soundscapes have?

Tags: atmosphere, measurements

Seems like the [Earth Day related crowd sourcing project](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/soundscape-recorder/) to create the first [global soundscape](https://globalsoundscapes.org/) by encouraging smartphone owners around the world to download and use an app developed to record the sounds around them is interesting, though it's unclear what scientific value it would have. **Is there any scientific value to understanding soundscapes on a global basis?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remote sensing using [passive sonar and seismograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_sensing#Acoustic_and_near-acoustic), which are
>   acoustic or near-acoustic signals, works on the principle of the
>   inverse problem. While the object or phenomenon of interest (the
>   state) may not be directly measured, there exists some other variable
>   that can be detected and measured (the observation), which may be
>   related to the object of interest through the use of a data-derived
>   computer model.
>
> [Soundscape ecology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundscape_ecology) is the study of sound within a landscape and
>   its effect on organisms. Sounds may be generated by organisms
>   (biophony), by the physical environment (geophony), or by humans
>   (anthrophony). Soundscape ecologists seek to understand how these
>   different sound sources interact across spatial scales and through
>   time. Variation in soundscapes may have wide-ranging ecological
>   effects as organisms often obtain information from environmental
>   sounds. Soundscape ecologists use recording devices, audio tools, and
>   elements of traditional ecological analyses to study soundscape
>   structure. Increasingly, anthrophony, sometimes referred to in older,
>   more archaic terminology as anthropogenic noise dominates soundscapes,
>   and this type of noise pollution or disturbance has a negative impact
>   on a wide range of organisms. The preservation of natural soundscapes
>   is now a recognized conservation goal.
>
> Source: Wikipedia links referenced above.